# Probability of events happening (this and/or that and/or etc.)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to calculate the probability that *any* a number events will occur. For instance you have 5 events that a 75% chance of happing how do you calculate the probability that *any* of the five will occur (be true)?

In my case I have a list of universities I want to apply to; given their acceptance rates I'd like to find my chance of success/failure. But I'll spare you the details. I really ought to know the math behind this. However I have found most explanations of this utterly unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chance that at least one event happens is the complement of the product of the chances that each of them doesn't happen, assuming they are independent.  So if you have events with probabilities $p,q,r$, the chance of at least one is $1-(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)$  I repeat:  this assumes they are independent.  There is probably some correlation between university A accepting a student and university B doing so.

Comment: @DavidMitra:  fixed